# How to extract subsets with overlaps from data frame in R

Tags: r

can anyone suggest a function for extracting the subsets from data frame? 
More specific: Let's say I have a data frame with 1000 rows. I want to create a data "window" containing 10 rows and calculating the standard deviation of the current "window" (subset) and move it by 5 rows further and doing it for the next "window". So, I don't want to skip any row, instead of it I want to have overlap of 5 rows between the "windows".
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `rollmean` from zoo package:

Example

```
> library(zoo) 
> x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2004, rep(1:4, 4:1), sample(1:28, 10), sep = "-"))
> set.seed(1)
> x<- zoo(rnorm(12), x.Date) # Creating a time series
> rollmean(x, 5) # obtaining the 5 days rolling mean.
2004-01-10 2004-01-11 2004-02-21 2004-02-27 2004-02-28 2004-03-13 
 0.1292699  0.3938814  0.3550785  0.1836873  0.2621149  0.1351357
```

In this example the moving windows is 5 and the "overlap" length is 1.

Take a look at `?rollmean` and also `?rollapply` can be helpful.

```
> rollapply(x, width=5, by=2, mean)
2004-01-10 2004-02-21 2004-02-28 
 0.1292699  0.3550785  0.2621149
```

Using `rollapply` allows you to vary the "overlaping" length through `by` argument. Note in this case the moveing windows is 5 while the "overlap" length is 2.

Comment: Thanks for reply! It seems interesting. Just to clarify: in this example the "window" length is 5 and what is the overlap length? Thanks!

Comment: @ArmMiner  See the edit. If I correctly undertand what you mean with "overlap" length, then you can use `rollapply` function and setting `by` argument to any value for the "overlap" length.

Comment: yeah it's correct: the two successive "windows" have in this case overlap of 2. So, instead of ´mean´ function in the argument I can use even my own functions, right?

Comment: Yes, when using `rollapply` you can use whatever function you want by plug in into the `FUN` argument, see `?rollapply` for further details, note that if your function has several arguments, you should use the `...` to pass those arguments of your function to `rollapply` :D